# Not saving lines when writing to CSV file using for-loop

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, web-scraping

So I'm trying to run a scrape of a website. The scraper runs very well. But whenever I try to write the scraped information/rows into the csv file it deletes the previous row. I end up just having the very last scrape result in the file at the end. I'm sure it's just an indentation error? I'm still new to Python so any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```
# create general field names
fields = ['name', 'about', 'job_title', 'location','company',
          'education','accomplishments','linkedin_url']

with open('ScrapeResults.csv', 'w') as f:
    # using csv.writer method from CSV package
    write = csv.writer(f)
    write.writerow(fields)
f.close()

# Loop-through urls to scrape multiple pages at once
for individual,link in contact_dict.items():

    ## assign ##
    the_name = individual
    the_link = link
    # scrape peoples url:
    person = Person(the_link, driver=driver, close_on_complete=False)

    # rows to be written
    rows = [[person.name, person.about, person.job_title, person.location, person.company,
             person.educations, person.accomplishments, person.linkedin_url]]
    # write
    with open('ScrapeResults.csv', 'w') as f:
    # using csv.writer method from CSV package
        write = csv.writer(f)
        write.writerows(rows)
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to open the file in **append** mode.

change

```py
with open('ScrapeResults.csv', 'w') as f:
```

to

```py
with open('ScrapeResults.csv', 'a') as f:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overwriting the file instead of appending it. Append mode in the for loop should fix the issue

```
with open('ScrapeResults.csv', "a")
```

Please refer python IO documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the file in **append mode**.

replace

```
with open('ScrapeResults.csv', 'w') as f:
```

to

```
with open('ScrapeResults.csv', 'a') as f:
```